# Does exists a tags field or something like tags in Mac OS for iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, user-interface, tags, tagging

I want to create a tags system for an iPhone app that let you type the tags names and appear like in some Mac OS software.

Like this:

http://www.leandroardissone.com/screenshots/tags-20100222-023617.png

Do you know if there's a way to do that? Or if there's a third party library for that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Three20](http://github.com/facebook/three20) project that is derived from Facebook iPhone app. Under samples You can find pretty cool tags handling implementation.

Comment: Ah, nice.. I'll see if I can get just that part, because Three20 lib was banned by Apple. Thanks.

Comment: What? When/why was it banned? Do you have any more info on this?

Comment: I found a discussion on this here: http://groups.google.com/group/three20/browse_thread/thread/c442af6e39a918b0/6d5046771539d139

Comment: @mjdth that's from last October, when Three20 was using private API.  you can definitely get versions of Three20 now that are "store safe"